# updating a column of database with existing data with a counter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a oracle database with a table that has existing data.
I want to add a field and update it with a counter that starts from 0001 which will continue like 0010,0011 ... 0100 and so on to existing data.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do those counter values represent **binary** values?

Comment: Why not just use an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described it, this might be one option:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test as select * from dept;

Table created.
```

Add the `counter` column:

```
SQL> alter table test add counter varchar2(4);

Table altered.
```

Update it:

```
SQL> update test set counter = lpad(rownum, 4, '0');

4 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           COUN
---------- -------------- ------------- ----
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      0001
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        0002
        30 SALES          CHICAGO       0003
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON        0004

SQL>
```

---

If counter is, actually, a binary representation, then you might use something like this:

```
SQL> alter table test add counter_binary varchar2(4);

Table altered.

SQL> merge into test t
  2    using(with temp as
  3            (select deptno, row_number() over (order by deptno) rn
  4             from test
  5            )
  6          select deptno,
  7            lpad(listagg(sign(bitand(rn, power(2, column_value - 1))), '')
  8            within group (order by column_value desc), 4, '0') bin
  9          from temp cross join
 10            table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                                connect by power(2, level - 1) <= rn
 12                               ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13          group by deptno) x
 14    on (t.deptno = x.deptno)
 15    when matched then update set t.counter_binary = x.bin;

4 rows merged.

SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           COUNTER    COUNTER_BINARY
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ---------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      0001       0001
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        0002       0010
        30 SALES          CHICAGO       0003       0011
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON        0004       0100

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful. I would also like to know if I could add counter by sorting some column in certain order.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorting: yes, here - put anything you want into the ORDER BY clause: `row_number() over (order by deptno)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **BITAND** function
It gives the next result:

```
SELECT BITAND(128, 128) FROM DUAL; --> 128
```

If you put

```
SELECT BITAND(127, 128) FROM DUAL; --> 0
```

and if you put

```
SELECT BITAND(255, 128) FROM DUAL; --> 128
```

So the rule is:

```
SELECT BITAND(M, N) FROM DUAL; IF M < N OR M >= 2*N --> 0
```

So to get your numbers you may to use this:

```
SELECT 
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 128), 128, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 64), 64, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 32), 32, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 16), 16, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 8), 8, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 4), 4, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 2), 2, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(my_value, 1), 1, '1', '0') as binary_number FROM
(SELECT <put_any_number> as my_value FROM DUAL) A;
```

From here you must to use a VARCHAR2 variable with INTO statement.